# Can't import react component library into CRA

Tags: reactjs

I created a react component library for a project to create a shareable component library across
multiple projects using the same theme and similar components.

I am importing it by `npm link` and importing as `import { Button } from 'ph-shared'`

It throws error
[image]

Here's the link to lib code if that can help
https://github.com/usmantahirr/react-lib

Comment: How CRA is aware of there is something called 'ph-shared', its neither present in your src nor present in the node_modules  folder, that's the reason it throws the error.

Comment: This is library code. This is to be imported. The project it is imported in has this mentioned. It is importing just fine, feels like it's throwing error for multiple versions of reacts being present.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. You have to install `react-app-rewired` and `react-app-rewired-alias`

here's the code snippit

const path = require('path');
const {alias} = require('react-app-rewire-alias')

Add a file `config-overrides.js` in root and put this.

```
// config-overrides.js
module.exports = function override(config) {
    alias({
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
    })(config)

    return config;
};
```

Modify `scripts` your `package.json` as follows

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```